# Does adding an object to an arraylist set the object's variables to null?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am creating an app for Android that tracks team stats and I am using an ArrayList to store the list of teams. Why doesn't the object save its fields within the ArrayList??

I have already tried creating a new team in the list then setting it equal to the old team. (`teamList.add(new TeamStats()); teamList.get(teamList.size()-1) = team;`) but this does not run and throws an error.

```
public class TeamStats implements Serializable {
    //General Info
    public String TeamName;
    public String School;
    public boolean needUpdate;
    //...
}   


ArrayList <TeamStats> teamList = new ArrayList<TeamStats>();

Intent intent = getIntent();
TeamStats team = (TeamStats) intent.getSerializableExtra("Team");

if (team != null && team.needUpdate == true){
    System.out.println("Name before list: " + team.TeamName);
    teamList.add(team);
    System.out.println("Name after list: " + 
        teamList.get(teamList.size()-1).TeamName);
    System.out.println("Same object? " + (team == teamList.get(teamList.size()-1)));
}

//iterates through teamList
for (int i = 0; i < teamList.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(teamList.get(i).TeamName);
    }
```

I expect the output to be:

```
Name before list: Alpha
Name after list: Alpha
Same object? true
Theta
Beta
Alpha
```

but the result I am getting is:

```
Name before list: Alpha
Name after list: null
Same object? true
Theta
Beta
Null
```

Comment: Can you double-check that this is the exact code you're running, and that you didn't leave `teamList.add(new TeamStats());` or something behind from your previous attempts, or forget to recompile after removing it? (If you rewrote or modified the code to clarify it before you posted it, please copy-paste it from your post back into your program to ensure that it still shows the wrong behavior.)

Comment: Add this line and run: `System.out.println("Same object? " + (team == teamList.get(teamList.size()-1)));`. This will tell you whether it is the same object we are dealing with.

Comment: I just checked and this is the correct code

Comment: The output says they are the same, but it still says null when I ask for the name.

Comment: Remove `team.needUpdate = false;` and try again.

Comment: Nothing changes, the output is still the same. The need update field is a field of the class and doesn't do anything currently

Comment: Can you show your ArrayList declaration?

Comment: Can you clone that object which you are getting from intent or create a dummy object and test it once? just for debugging? I am suspecting if someone else is doing this changes.

Comment: Copy/Paste the TeamStats class here plz

Comment: I am quite sure now if some other part of code this object reference is getting changed. Pls add the clone of the object getting from Intent will solve your problem.

Comment: `intent.getSerializableExtra` does this in any way contain asynchronous data or public static variables?

Comment: @ShivangAgarwal what do you mean by cloning to tests?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I dont know, how could i check? `intent.getSerializableExtra` is a method from the android development kit.

Comment: How do you get `Beta` and `Theta` and then `null`, since you are only adding 1 object to your arraylist? It seems that there is some part of the code that you did not share that causes the overwrite

Comment: Object cloning. create a new object clone all values fron existing into new object and then test it by adding that new object into list.

Comment: @P.Soutzikevich I am doing  `teamList.add(new TeamStats());
        teamList.get(0).TeamName = "Beta";` but that is only because those are constants and I know the index and all information of the team and the one im trying to do now is undetermined and doesn't exist at the start.

Comment: You really need to post everything you are doing - if you are running teamList.get(0).TeamName = "Beta"; on every element it will iterate through 3 elements and set the first element's name to Beta three times

Comment: @SandySimonton im not running it on every element? im doing `teamList.get(0).TeamName = "Beta" on index 0.

Comment: Ok thanks... I can tell you 100% it's not related to ArrayList, as I was able to add an element just fine and it "retained" the variable assignment as I thought it would. Usually these problems are related to "==" resolving as true in cases when you don't expect it, or not setting the value in the first place, or printing out two different values. Check again